# How to run watchOS app on iPhone?

Tags: apple-watch

I'm trying to write my first watchOS app. I don't have an actual Apple Watch yet so I wanted to see if I could test it on my iPhone 7. So I wrote a basic Hello World app, and I can see that when I run it on my phone, it loads the launchscreen storyboard first and then moves onto the Main storyboard. But when will the app then move onto the Interface storyboard which is where the "Hello world!" on a Watch-sized screen is printed?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run the watch app on an iPhone for testing.  When you create the watch app in Xcode, you can use an Xcode simulator to run the watch app on your computer for testing.  This way you can test without having an Apple Watch.

Answer (score 0):

iPhone app runs in iPhone/iPad/iPod with same UI if app is not universal.

If app is universal, then same app can be run on iPhone/iPad/iPod but XIBs/Interface may vary for iPad and iPhone/iPod.

watchOS app runs on watch either via Simulator or directly on watch with iPhone pairing.

watchOS app has two parts - WatchKit app and WatchKit extension. Both boxed under the iPhone bundle.